# Automation Tools / Action Recorder

Tags: software-rec, automation

Is there software that lets me record my actions and just play them again? 
I need software that lets me record my actions and allows me to input some variables like (from Excel file: list of name, list of email, list of website). The software must be able to interact with a browser and Windows applications since it would go to websites and send some files from my computer.

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would probably go for Autohotkey.  It records macros, and can play them back either by creating an exe file, or using a hotkey.

http://www.autohotkey.com/

Answer (score 1):

[Windows Macro Recorder](http://freelabs.info/MacroRecorder.aspx) does exactly that.

- Record all mouse and keystrokes events of any windows application
- Play back recorded macro.
- Save recorded macro to disk
- Load a macro from disk
- Light indicator when recording process is running
- Hide window to tray
- Repeat option
- Command line options

[image]

Windows Macro Recorder is freeware.

Answer (score 0):

The classic choice is: Autohotkey/[Autoit](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/index.shtml) for Windows, Automator for Mac and the iMacros IE/Firefox/Chrome addons for [web browser automation](http://wiki.imacros.net/iMacros_for_Firefox)